# Apache is turned off (Windows 7) but still serves web pages

Tags: windows-7, apache-2.2

I am running apache 2.2 on Windows 7. When I stop the apache service (verified in the Windows services and processes windows) and then go to access my web pages, it still loads my web pages.

I have cleared my cache, and I have tried loading in multiple browsers.

How is this possible?

Comment: The server is obviously still running somewhere... The "magic smoke" in computers is satire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up Task Manager, make sure you click "Show All Users", and look for instances of `httpd.exe`.

double-check your IP address.

Double-check that the page really is being served from apache, and not IIS or IIS Express or some other webserver. Best way I know how to do this is to use Firebug, or Chrome/Safari's developer tools to look at the Network tab and inspect the page's response header. It will usually have a clue as to which server/service is responding.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, i found out that httpd.exe was running. now should both apache.exe and httpd.exe be running at the same time? I'm running apache with fastcgi

Comment: depends on the platform and version of apache. The apache core spawns instances of httpd as request handlers. (rather than IIS that uses child processes) So what I'd say is that you're probably checking too early. One of the httpd instances isn't shutting down cleanly after stopping the service. Maybe a long-running process?

Comment: Stopping the Apache service just stops Apache from spawning more `httpd` processes. It doesn't necessarily terminate the ones already running.